# Join two lists without lookup column using caml query and sharepoint web services

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, caml-query, joined-view

I have 2 lists with the following columns:

- list1

  - City
  - ID
- list2

  - Customer
  - ID

I need to join these two lists on the basis of similar ID, I can't use the lookup column method. How can it be possible?

(using SharePoint online, CAML query and SharePoint web services)

Comment: join list and show how ?